# Чи використовують в сучасній мові слово "штиб"?

Tags: вживання-слів, вибір-слова

Згідно Академічному тлумачному словнику ШТИБ - чол., розм. Те саме, що кшталт. Синонім, тобто можна використовувати для розширення словникого запасу, але чи актуальне таке використання, на вашу думку?

Comment: Коло слова стоїть позначення розмовне (розм.), тому, на мою думку його використання актуальне.

Comment: [Особисто](/search?q=штиб) вживаю.

Comment: Я змушений проголосувати за закриття цього запитання. Причини: (1) ви посилаєтеся на словник, який вже вказує на використання («розм.» = розмовна мова). То у чому полягає запитання?; (2) не пояснене слово «актуальне». Ми можемо обʼєктивно говорити про усталеність, а актуальність — це опитування громадської думки або голосування; (3) «на вашу думку» — це завжди погано. Думки у кожного — свої, і тому Stack Exchange такі запитання не заохочує. Натомість, відповіді мають ґрунтуватися на поважних дослідженнях та джерелах, а власна думка не може бути основою відповіді.